# Load data in database without refreshing web page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, django, html, css

What is the best way or the best programming language or tool to use if i want to load data from web page in a database without refreshing the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX from the web page to send data to the backend, then the backend should take care of the data received to save it in the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("click", ".load", function(event) {
  var id =  $( this ).attr( "data-id" );

  $.ajax({
        method: "POST",url: "/url/to/ajax",
        data: {id: id}
  }).done(function( data ) {
      $( "body").html(data);
  });
});
```